# How to make Azure Search run on demand with Blob Storage

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search, azure-sdk-.net

I am using the Azure Search to index word documents automatically that are uploaded to Blob storage. The only reason I am using Search is to extract the text from the Word or PDF document ([it's free and works well](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-unstructured-search)) - from that point on I read it from the index and remove it.

The problem I have is that the Search Index can only run every 5 minutes -  I need it to run ASAP after a blob upload. So I either need to run it on demand (triggered every time a new blob is added) OR figure out how to insert the Word/PDF document into the index (or how to extract the text from it)

The flow is therefore:

1. Upload document to blob (Azure Function)
2. Index runs and extracts the text from document (Search Indexer)
3. Read the index periodically and extract that text for use elsewhere (Azure Function)

So my question is:

A. Is there a better way of extracting text natively from a word/pdf document using Azure? (in which case Question 2 is void)
B. How can I used the .NET SDK to invoke the Index to Run (I could not find a Run method [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.search.iindexesoperations?view=azure-dotnet)) although several places mention you can run it on demand with the SDK.

Comment: The second method at that link is `CreateOrUpdateWithHttpMessages` which apparently _Creates a new Azure Search index or updates an index if it already exists._ Don't you just want to update an index?

Comment: I don't think so - I want to cause the Index to process the new Blob document (which internally is extracting the text from the PDF). I don't have the text myself and haven't found a way to extract it (besides the slightly hacky way I am doing above)

Comment: This is part B of your question above - refresh the index on demand.

Comment: Are you trying to just extract text from new documents as part of a processing pipeline or are you trying to maintain a search index of all documents loaded?

Comment: So I need to trigger the index to run its internal processes of looking for new blobs and indexing them. I thought the Update method required you to provide the source data to give to the index, which is not what I need

Comment: I have not used this indexer before but they usually work by indexing the whole 'catalog' not just new pieces. You should using this method or the web API mentioned below to see what it does.

Comment: Ok, thanks Nick - it does seem to have a Run method on the REST api but not on the SDK. However using Search was only ever a stopgot to get the document extraction text - I will switch this to use Tika as it removes a lot of complexity that I didn't need (although Search service is pretty impressive - will probably use it elsewhere in solution).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you *only* need Azure Search for document cracking, and don't need the rest of the search and enrichment functionalities, it may be simpler to do document cracking directly in an Azure Function. There are many OSS and commercial libraries for document parsing, e.g. [Apache Tika](http://tika.apache.org/).

An [example](https://github.com/liamca/AzureSearch-AzureFunctions-CognitiveServices/tree/master/ApacheTika) of using Tika from an Azure Function, written by one of our team members.

Comment: Yes, that is all I am using it for, and it does it really well, along with cognitive analytis (e.g. keyword extraction) and possibly I will need OCR in the future. At the very least I need it to be able to extract Word and PDF - thanks for the link, I'll check it out

Comment: Also, as mentioned by a previous commenter, you can run an indexer on demand. See [Run Indexer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/run-indexer)

Comment: Ok, it looks like it's time to switch to Tika - it seems to do what I need (all type of Word docs and pdfs) and it removes the whole of Search Index from the equation. It would be great if Azure could expose the extraction part of the indexer service as a new service so I could use Azure for this instead of another external dependency. I appreciate the answers - it's got me back on track